# How to scale prometheus in kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, prometheus

I have reached moment when I need to split my prometheus into smaller ones.
I have been reading about it [here](https://www.robustperception.io/scaling-and-federating-prometheus/) but it does not say anything about scaling in kubernetes. Below is my setup:

- one node of prometheus
- one node of [kube state metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics)
- [node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) on each cluster node

and there are about 50 namespaces which produces thousands of metrics and one current setup with one prometheus is not enough. So I decided to split it to three instances like:

- one for [kube state metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) metrics
- one for [node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) metrics
- one for kubernetes metrics

But after while i realised that those metrics are scraped by [kubernetes_sd_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#<kubernetes_sd_config) and there is no way to tell which metrics I want to scrape by which instance of prometheus or I am wrong.
One solution would be to split kubernetes cluster into smaller one but it is too much work for now.

So my question is if there is any possibility to tell prometheus that I want scrape only [kube state metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics), [node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) or native kubernetes metrics ?

Comment: One solution that I am thonking of is to not add annotation to exporters services for prometheus and configure static configuration for them

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be going for a horizontally scalable, distributed Prometheus implementation: https://github.com/weaveworks/cortex (NB I wrote this.)

Its not ready for prime time yet, but we're using it internally and getting pretty good results.  It will be more effort to setup and operate than upstream Prometheus, but it should scale virtually indefinitely - and what's more we run it on Kubernetes, so it's really at home there.

Let me know if you're interested and I can walk you though setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling in Kubernetes is the same as elsewhere. This is a question of using service discovery and relabelling to pick out what is monitored.

For example the configuration for the node exporters should already be a separate scrape_config so splitting it out to a separate Prometheus should be straightforward by splitting the configuration file.

Comment: what kind of scrape_config should I create ? static ?

Comment: Right now i use kubernetes_sd_config with annotations in services.
btw does relabeling allows to filter metrics or just labels from metrics ?

Comment: so how this separate scrape_config should looks like for node exporter? Right now I am using let say default kubernetes_sd_config and node exporter is deployed as daemonset with service which is annotated for prometheus.

Comment: isn't it similar to https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2280 ?

Comment: The issue is about something else, it's a discussion on not doing API requests to certain namespaces of the Kubernetes API, so we're talking about Kubernetes object namespaces nothing to do with Prometheus per se.

What Brian is talking about is that you have separate Prometheus instances for each of those. 1 for scraping node-exporters, 1 for kube-state-metrics, 1 for all other metrics. This is called functional sharding. Once you hit a limit with functional sharing you can start sharding the targets as explained in the blog post to have more than one Prometheus instance for each of those.

Comment: I got it, but I do not know how to do this functional sharding with kubernetes_sd_config. Is there any possibility to specify targets in kubernetes_sd_config ? I could do this with `static_config` but it is not best solution in kubernetes.

Comment: Maybe I should try prometheus operator by coreos

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task for federation. Here is how I did, following @brian-brazil answer:

- setup a `master` prometheus with config:

`scrape_configs:
      - job_name: dc_prometheus
        honor_labels: true
        metrics_path: /federate
        params:
          match[]:
          - '{job="my-kubernetes-job"}'
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - prometheus-slaveA:9090
            - prometheus-slaveB:9090`

See how slaves are declared here. It's quite static for sure.
Also, the `match[]` param here tells to grab all slave metrics. You would have to be smarter than that of course.

- setup `slaves` with that particular relabeling:

`relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_slave]
            action: keep
            regex: slaveA`

and similar for slaveB and so on.

Now for each pod, instead of having the well-known annotation `prometheus.io/scrape: true|false`, you would have `prometheus.io/slave: slaveA|slaveB`.

I described it with more details here: http://devlog.qaraywa.net/?p=176